# Unable to create share for Transit Gateway via AWS Resource Access Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, transit-gateway

The resource you are attempting to share can only be shared within your AWS Organization. This error may also occur if you have not enabled sharing with your AWS organization, or that onboarding process is still in progress.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enable trusted access. Without it, sharing of transit gateway will not proceed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the Settings section in the AWS RAM Console.

Select the box **Enable sharing with AWS Organizations**, and then choose **Save settings**.